# how to set the start value of the autoincrement primary key field in liquibase

Tags: liquibase

I have a requirement like, my mysql table's primary key starts with '0'. How should i specify it in liquibase xml?

I have tried startWith parameter while creating the table but it doesn't work out.

```
    <column autoIncrement="true" name="id" type="BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED" startWith="0">
            <constraints primaryKey="true"/>
        </column>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL generated by liquibase appears to be correctly including the AUTO_INCREMENT=0 table option based on your startWith. You can see the generated SQL if you run `liquibase updateSql`

Running the SQL directly, MySQL itself appears to not accept a default value of zero. If I use the same createTable but use a different startWith like 100 it works fine, but setting it to zero makes it actually start with one.

Perhaps setting the `SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";` flag will make it work correctly, but since mysql uses zero as the value meaning "use the next auto-increment field" it may be better to start with 1 if you can to avoid confusion.